# str object is not callable when inserting into SQLite database

Tags: python, string, sqlite

I am working on a temperature sensor network using onewire temperature sensors that runs on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I am following [this tutorial](http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/rpi-temperature-logger) and as I was going along, I realized that his setup is for one temperature sensor, whereas my setup needs to work with multiple sensors.

As a result of having multiple sensors, I also need to be able to differentiate the sensors from one another.  To do this, I want to have 3 columns in the SQLite table.  I am encountering the error when I execute the Python script that is supposed to log the readout from the sensor, the date and time, and the sensor name.

Here is the problem, when I am configuring the python script to write three values to the table, I get an error.

[image]

Here is the code that I am getting an error when executing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3

import os
import time
import glob

# global variables
speriod=(15*60)-1
dbname='/var/www/templog.db'

# store the temperature in the database
def log_temperature(temp):

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    sensor1 = 'Sensor1'

    curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?,?))" (temp, sensor1)) 

    # commit the changes
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?,?))" (temp, sensor1)
```

Breaking this down you will see that this creates a string and then the parenthesis appears to Python to be a function call. However this is nonsensical because you have a string that you are trying to call like it is a function. Hence the error you get about `str` not being callable, this is definitely a bit cryptic if you are not experienced with Python. Essentially you are missing a comma:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?,?))", (temp, sensor1))
```

Now you will get the `?` placeholders correctly filled in.

Often the "`str` is not callable" error will be a result of typos such as this or duplicated variable names (you think you are calling a function but the variable really contained a string), so start by looking for those problems when you see this type of error.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a `,` there:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO temps values(datetime('now'), (?,?))" , (temp, sensor1))
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

> Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the ***second argument*** to the cursor’s `execute()` method

As you can see you need to provide the tuple as the second argument to the function `execute`